# How to create a singleton pattern for SignalR in React Native

Tags: react-native, signalr

This react native project uses SignalR to get live updates from a .NET core server. I currently have a functional component that handles SignalR hub connections and it is imported in `App.js` but in doing so, the App is creating new connections on certain rerenders. How do I ensure that there is singleton pattern when using `@microsoft/signalr`?

This is the current code:

```
const SignalR = () => {
  const [connection, setConnection] = useState(null);

  if (!connection) {
    const conn = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl(`${url.api}/latest`, {
        accessTokenFactory: async () => {
          const creds = JSON.parse(await getCredentials());
          if (!creds) {
            return null;
          }
          const token = await B2CAuthentication.getInstance().assureToken(
            creds,
          );
          return token;
        },
      })
      .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Warning)
      .withAutomaticReconnect()
      .build();

    conn
      .start()
      .then(async () => {
        request({url.api}).then(async () => {
          await console.log('Connected to SignalR');
        });
      })
      .catch(async () => {
        await console.log('Error starting SignalR');
      });

    setConnection(conn);

  return <></>;
};

export default SignalR;
```

Comment: Where is the setConnection function used?

Comment: @gwl002 added more code to show that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a function component to do this, anytime the App component update, the SignalR component will reRun.I think you can do this just use a useEffect with no dependency.

```
//in App.js
useEffect(()=>{
  const conn = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl(`${url.api}/latest`, {
    accessTokenFactory: async () => {
      const creds = JSON.parse(await getCredentials());
      if (!creds) {
        return null;
      }
      const token = await B2CAuthentication.getInstance().assureToken(
        creds,
      );
      return token;
    },
  })
  .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Warning)
  .withAutomaticReconnect()
  .build();

  const restart = () => {
    if (!conn) {
      return;
    }
    if (conn.state !== signalR.HubConnectionState.Disconnected) {
      return;
    }
    try {
      await conn.start();
    } catch (err) {
      setTimeout(restart, 5000);
    }
  }

  conn.onclose(() => {
    console.log('Disconnected. Restarting.');
    restart();
  });


  conn.start()
  .then(async () => {
    request({url.api}).then(async () => {
      await console.log('Connected to SignalR');
    });
  })
  .catch(async () => {
    await console.log('Error starting SignalR');
  });

},[])
```

Comment: I have something like that right now but it's starting new connections on re-render. Ideally, I'd like to have one connection for the entire lifecycle of the application unless it gets disconnected and needs to reestablish a new connection.

Comment: If you use useEffect without dependency, the function will only execute once.The connection will only restart when closed.